# UIWebView access to an installed certificate (.p12 file)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, certificate, keychain

I have an app that contains an `UIWebView` and I need to authenticate the user with the correct certificate.

Is it possible to get access to an imported/installed `certificate` in the keychain? I didn't find something that's similar to my problem.

Comment: From where you are getting authentication information ? you can save authentication data in userdefault like on login or service call save the authentication status and load UIWebView if the user's authentication status is valid or meeting your criteria .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I have an self-signed certificate with some informations and my web server needs an authentication of the client too. I googled and find out that I don't get access from `UIWebView` to the file system or keychain. Only to items the app imported